# Set environment variables in bash file calling a Matlab script

Tags: bash, matlab, environment-variables

I have the following bash file launching some Matlab m-files (main.m and f.m which are scripts) 4 times (4 tasks).

```
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=4G
#$ -l tmem=4G
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 4 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging from 1 to 4
#$ -t 1-4

#$ -N example
date
hostname

#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

/share/apps/[...]/matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
```

The f.m script uses the Gurobi toolbox and I have been told that in order for the file to execute properly I have to set the environment variable

```
GRB=/apps/[...].lic
```

where [...] contains the path.

I am a very beginner on how to write bash files and I apologise if my question is silly: where/how/what should I write on the batch file above to use the Gurobi toolbox?

I have googled on how to set environment variables but I got confused between setting, exporting, env. There are many similar questions on in this forum but, since they apply to apparently differently structured batch files, I couldn't understand whether their answers can be tailored also to my case.

Comment: Replaced the obviously wrong tag [batch-file] with [bash]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your bash file, just add the following line **before** launching the matlab m-files:

```
export GRB="/apps/[...].lic"
```

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables are owned by a process, a running process can't change environment of another running process, when creating a new process exported variables of parent are set in child process by default, the environment variables changed in child process can't affect parent process.

`GRB=/apps/[...].lic` will set variable `GRB` to a value in `bash` process it can be seen using `echo "$GRB"` for example but this variable is not exported, means that when calling `matlab`, for `matlab` process environment variable `GRB` will not be set. Using `export GRB` before calling `matlab` will make the variable exported to matlab process.

There's also a syntax to set environment variable for a new process without affecting current bash process: `GRB=/apps/[...].lic /share/apps/[...]/matlab ...`.

For further details `man bash` `/export` `/^ENVIRONMENT`

Also compare output of following commands, set (a builtin, a bash "function" no new process created), env (/usr/bin/env a command, a new process is created and  only sees exported variables)

```
$ set
$ env
```

the first shows variables, whereas the second environnment which is a subset of first.